# Error when trying to create doctrine database with phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine, mamp

I'm a fresh junior php developer and I'm building my first Symfony project.

When I used the command : `php bin/console doctrine:database:create`
I get these errors :

> In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 93:
>     An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
>
> In PDOConnection.php line 31:
>     SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
>
> In PDOConnection.php line 27:
>     SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory*

---

I'm actually using MAMP with default config "db_user" and "db_password"
so I edited the .env file with this following code : 
`DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:root@localhost:8889/mydbname`

I know there is something wrong with my host or port, I saw on other topics that some users using MAMP keep Symfony default values for host and port : `DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:root@127.0.0.1:3306/mydbname`

Thanks for reading me and trying to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did more searches and some people are saying that localhost syntax is depreciated and prefer using : `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`.

In my case I checked and used Mamp config 'Connect using an UNIX socket'

So it's now working with :

### `DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:root@127.0.0.1:8889/mydbname`